# Passing values to Bootstrap4 popover

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I have a loop rendered table (Flask/Jinja), and i want to be able to edit one of the record in a column quickly, so i have  choosen to use a bs4 popover to render a select field (filled by jinja) inside a form.

Since it might not be a good idea to render one hidden form per result, I have to figure a way to set a hidden field in that form so i know what record im editing. but i always get "1"...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      sanitize: false,
      content: function() {
        let editar = $("#editicon").data("id")
        console.log(editar);
        $(".input-group input").val( editar );

          return $('#PopoverContent').html()
      }
      })
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <td id="sts-estado"> {{ pedido.status }}
        <i data-id={{pedido.id}} id="editicon" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#PopoverContent" data-trigger="click" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover"></i></td>
    <td> {{ pedido.contact }}</td>
```

near the end of the html:

```
    <div id="PopoverContent" class="d-none">
    <form role="form" class="statuseditform" name="form1">
      <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="hidden" name="editing" id="editing" value=""/>

                     <select name="status" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="{{statuses[0][0]}}" selected="{{statuses[0][0]}}">{{statuses[0][1]}}</option>
                        {% for status in statuses[1:] %}
                            <option value="{{status[0]}}">{{status[1]}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

          <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon1">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
              data-html="true" data-title="Search">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. Still not the right solution. I've created a listener for the popover show event in which it gets the data-id of event.currentTarget and sets the form input field.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('show.bs.popover', function (event) {
    var edititem = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'];
    $(".input-group input").val( edititem.value );
});
```